# bootstrap input aligned with button

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have on the same line: text, search box and the button "Locate", but the following code seems not working because what I get is: the text "Map for network..." aligned with the input box while the "Locate" button is below the input box. Any suggestion?

```
<div style="border-color:#FCD229; margin-bottom:0px" class="panel panel-primary">
  <!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div style="border-color:#FCD229; background-color:#FCD229"class="panel-heading">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-8">Map for Network<p class="badge"><?php echo $net_name ?></p></label>
      <div class="form-horizontal col-lg-4">
        <input id="marker_id" name="address" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="node name..">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Locate</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSFiddle "Answer"**

To cut to the chase - you can look at the result of my tests on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eThej/. **NOTE** - Bootstrap is responsive so you need to make the window with the preview large enough or the controls will wrap to the next line. This is intentional to allow for forms to work on smaller screens (responsive design).

**Explanation / Notes**

I believe the following example (pulled from the bootstrap site) does something like what you are looking for:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

I took your code and applied a few changes to it and got a similar result. First - you are looking for a form with a class of "form-inline". Second, if you are using a column layout I think you probably want "md" columns and not "lg" columns. Finally I think you div's aren't nested correctly. It isn't pretty but I applied these few changes and got much closer to what I think you want. The following is that result:

```
<div style="border-color:#FCD229; margin-bottom:0px" class="panel panel-primary">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div style="border-color:#FCD229; background-color:#FCD229" class="panel-heading">

        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="control-label">Map for Network</label>
                <p class="badge">Test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group"><input id="marker_id" name="address" class="form-control input-sm"
                    type="text" placeholder="node name.." />
                </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Locate</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, not a perfect answer but I think it should get you on the right track. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be more suitable for what I had in mind.

```
<div style="border-color:#FCD229; margin-bottom:0px" class="panel panel-primary">
                    <!-- Default panel contents -->

                    <div style="border-color:#FCD229; background-color:#FCD229"class="panel-heading">


                        <label class="control-label col-lg-8">Map for Network Test</label>
                         <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                          <input id="" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Node Name">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Locate</button>
                          </span>
                         </div><!-- /input-group -->

                     </div>


                    </div>
```